# maintain session between the pages in php?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session

I am very new to PHP.

I want to transfer data between pages.

In my requirements I have the home page first, in that I have 3 fields: *name*, *address*, *pin* and then *submit button*.

When I entered the above fields and then click on submit, it moves to `page2.php`, it has form data.

I have transferred the first form data to second page. Now in second page I have a submit button. When I click on that button the data is submitted to a MySQL database.

My problem is, how can I move first page values to `insertdata.php` page and submit the data ?

Comment: What did you try? Start from here: [PHP: Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways with which you can do this

1. Sessions
2. Hidden input fields

## Sessions

To pass data from one page to another, you first need to call `session_start()` on all pages that are going to use `$_SESSION` superglobal variable.
Then you can store your values in sessions by using

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['address'];
$_SESSION['pin'] = $_POST['pin'];
```

To use these values in the second page, simply call them by their names. Ex:

```
$name = $_SESSION['name']; // will contain the value entered in first page
```

==================================================================================

## Hidden Input Fields

This is more of a tedious approach but it does the job none the less. The process involves storing data that needs to be passed onto to different pages in hidden fields and later accessing them via the `$_POST` or `$_GET` superglobal.

**page1.php** (which posts to page2.php)

```
<input type="text" value="Page 1 content" name="content" />
<input type="text" value="Page 1 body" name="body" />
```

**page2.php** (which posts to page3.php)

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['content']; ?>" name="content" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['body']; ?>" name="body" />
<input type="text" value="Page 2 content" name="content2" />
<input type="text" value="Page 2 body" name="body2" />
```

**page3.php**

```
echo $_POST['content']; // prints "Page 1 content"
echo $_POST['body']; // prints "Page 1 body"
echo $_POST['content2']; // prints "Page 2 content"
echo $_POST['body2']; // prints "Page 2 body"
```

Comment: +1 for hidden input fields, although you didn't explain them much.

Comment: @AlexLunix Thanks. I didn't go into hidden fields because the process is a bit longer and sessions beat hidden fields hands down. Anyways, I will add explanation about it once I get home.

Comment: What do you mean by "declare `session_start()`"? Because, coming from C, that means "create a function called `session_start()`", which doesn't seem like what you meant.

Comment: @NicHartley Perhaps I should have phrased it better. By "declare", I meant "call a function".

Answer (score 1):

just use the below code in your first page `<?php session_start(); ?>`
and use the following code in your sencond page

```
<?php
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$address = $_SESSION['address'];
$pin = $_SESSION['pin'];
echo $name."<br/>";
echo $address."<br/>";
echo $pin."<br/>";
?>
```

or you can use `post` or `get` method as below

For GET Method

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
$address = $_GET['address'];
$pin = $_GET['pin'];
echo $name."<br/>";
echo $address."<br/>";
echo $pin."<br/>";
?>
```

For POST METHOD

```
    <?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $pin = $_POST['pin'];
    echo $name."<br/>";
    echo $address."<br/>";
    echo $pin."<br/>";
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like `REQUEST`, PHP maintains a map for session in which you could dump these values and across the pages. 
e.g.

```
$_SESSION['name']='foo';
```

But the page where you would like to use session, you need to start the session using the method `session_start();` . But this method call should be the first line in your php.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Please don't refer people to w3schools. See here for reasons http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: Sure. I will correct myself in future. Thanks for this article.

Comment: In case anyone reads the first comment, the link cited now includes the text 'Today, W3Schools has largely resolved these issues and addressed the majority of the undersigned developers' concerns. For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience.' Therefore, that comment should be deleted as it is no longer applicable.

Answer (score 0):

To store data between page changes, you can use the superglobal $_SESSION array.

*Example*

**Page 1**

```
$_SESSION['name'] = "John";
```

**Page 2**

```
echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

**Output**

```
John
```

Make sure you put `session_start()` at the top of each page that requires the use of sessions.

[Click here for more information on Sessions.](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you submit the data in the first page save them in the session then redirect to the second page.

In the second page just load them.

Page 1:

```
<?php session_start(); 

     $_SESSION["var_name"]  = $some_value;


?>
```

page 2:

```
<?php session_start(); 

     $my_var = $isset($_SESSION["var_name"])?$_SESSION["var_name"]:null;




?>
```

you test the value of my_var, if it's empty then redirect to the first page or show an error message.

session tutorial 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Mysql insert tutorial 
http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlinsert.php

POST/GET tutorial 
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/postget.php